# Deploy tomcat in the silent mode using install4J

Tags: install4j

I'm a newbie. I tried making an installer with my application and bundled the tomcat within it. When the installer runs, its prompting the tomcat installation screens to the user. Can we deploy the tomcat in silent mode, with a default location given?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That depends on the Tomcat installer, maybe it has a silent command line parameter such as "-q"

Comment: I'm using install4j 4. How we can integrate the command line option like net start tomcat in the installr

Comment: You use a "Run executable action" and pass all the required parameters to it. The executable is "${installer:sys.system32Dir}/net.exe" and the arguments are "start;tomcat" (separated by semicolons)